# React JS: How to Create a preview page from the current view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a React component that takes inputs from other components to display text of various size in a view. Since it is basically a form, what I want to do is pass the current view into another page where I will then post that view to my database as JSON.

Since the state of the input fields are not set in this component, I'm not sure how I would pass them as props to a new view.

This is a condensed version of what my data input component looks like:

`INPUTSHOW.JSX`

```
export default class InputShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    autosize(this.textarea);
  }

  render() {
    const { node } = this.props;
...

    return (
      <div className="editor-div" >
        {
          (node.type === 'buttonA') ?

            <textarea
              style={hlArea}
              ref={a => (this.textarea = a)}
              placeholder="type some text"
              rows={1}
              defaultValue=""
              id={node.id} className='editor-input-hl' type="text" onChange={this.props.inputContentHandler} />

            :
            (node.type === 'buttonB')
              ?

              <textarea
                style={subArea}
                ref={b => (this.textarea = b)}
                placeholder="type some text"
                rows={1}
                defaultValue=""
                id={node.id} className='editor-input-sub' type="text" onChange={this.props.inputContentHandler} />

              :   
        ""
        }
      </div >
    )
  }
}
```

This works fine in creating inputs in a current view. I then pass those values to `TextAreaField.JSX`

```
export default (props) => {
  return (

    <>
      <button><Link to={{
        pathname: '/edit/preview',
        text: props.inputsArray
      }}>preview</Link></button>

      <div className='view'>
        {
          props.inputsArray.map(
            (node, key) => <InputShow key={key} node={node} inputContentHandler={props.inputContentHandler} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

and then finally that is rendered in my `Edit.JSX` form:

```
export default class Edit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    UniqueID.enableUniqueIds(this);
    this.state = {
      inputs: [],
      text: ''
    }
  }

...

  createPage = async () => {
    await this.props.postPage(this.state.text)
  }



  // Handler for listen from button.
  buttonCheck = (e) => {
    index++;
    const node = {
      id: this.nextUniqueId() + index,
      type: e.target.id,
      text: '',
      image: true
    }
    this.setState(
      prev => ({
        inputs: [...prev.inputs, node]
      })
    )
    console.log(this.state.inputs);
  }

  inputContentHandler = (e) => {
    let newArray = this.state.inputs;
    let newNode = newArray.find((node) => {
      return (node.id === e.target.id)
    })
    newNode.text = e.target.value;

    this.setState({ inputs: newArray });
    console.log(this.state.inputs);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <InnerHeader />
        <div className='some-page-wrapper'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className="dash-card-sm">
              <br />
              <EditButtonContainer buttonCheck={this.buttonCheck} />

              <Route path='/edit/form' render={() => (
                <TextAreaField
                  inputsArray={this.state.inputs}
                  inputContentHandler={this.inputContentHandler}
                />
              )}
              />

              <Route path='/edit/preview' render={(props) => (
                <Preview
                  inputs={this.state.inputs}
                  text={this.state.text}
                  createPage={this.createPage}
                />
              )}
              />
              <br />   <br />
              {/* Button Header */}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how I should be passing the rendered view to the `Preview.jsx`component.  I'm still new to react (4 months)...Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.